# How to create a line plot in python, by importing data from excel and using it to create a plot that shares a common X-Axis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, spyder

Trying to create a plot using Python Spyder. I have sample data in excel which I am able to import into Spyder, I want one column ('Frequency') to be the X axis, and the rest of the columns ('C1,C2,C3,C4') to be plotted on the Y axis. How do I do this? This is the data in excel and how the plot looks in excel (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRug5.png) , [the plot and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1W6w.png)

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c70zD.png) . These commands below (Also seen in the image) give an empty plot.

data = data.head()

#data.plot(kind='line', x='Frequency', y=['C1','C2','C3','C4'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Frequency","C1", "C2","C3","C4"])

df.plot(x = "Frequency",y=["C1", "C2","C3","C4"])

Comment: Please provide your data in tabular form, or as the result of `df.to_dict()` (or `data.to_dict()`).

Comment: Thanks for responding! This is just a sample data, I have data with the same number of columns and 400 data points to plot.

Comment: Please provide your *sample* data as tabular form or as the result of `df.to_dict()`. See [ask], which specifically says to avoid screenshots of code/data/errors.

Comment: {'Frequency ': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 200, 4: 500}, 'C1': {0: 12, 1: 10, 2: 8, 3: 6, 4: 4}, 'C2': {0: 12, 1: 4, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: -5}, 'C3': {0: 17, 1: 10, 2: -10, 3: 4, 4: 1}, 'C4': {0: -7, 1: -2, 2: 10, 3: -5, 4: -2}}

Comment: this sample data has been extracted from an excel sheet. This just a random sample, however 5 cols and 6 rows. My real data has 5 cols and 400 rows. My question (1) is how can i call Frequency which is x-axis and is common to C1,C2,C3,C4. (2) how can i have C1,C2,C3, and C4 plotted on the Y-axis with the common X-axis on the same chart?

Comment: I am thinking of extracting all the values from the Frequency dictionary, and assign that to x-axis, but I am unable to extract it using ---> print(dict1['Frequency.keys()']) however, I am getting this error : 'File "C:\Users\Alisha.Walia\Desktop\Alisha\Sample.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(dict1['Frequency.keys()'])     KeyError: 'Frequency.keys()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


path = r"C:\Users\Alisha.Walia\Desktop\Alisha\SAMPLE.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(path)

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
#print(df)
#prints out data from excl in tabular format

dict1 = (data.to_dict()) #print(dict1)


Frequency=data["Frequency "].to_list() #print (Frequency)

C1=data["C1"].to_list() #print(C1)
C2=data["C2"].to_list() #print(C2)
C3=data["C3"].to_list() #print(C3)
C4=data["C4"].to_list() #print(C4)


plt.plot(Frequency,C1)
plt.plot(Frequency,C2)
plt.plot(Frequency,C3)
plt.plot(Frequency,C4)


plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.title('SAMPLE')
plt.xlabel('Frequency 20Hz-200MHz')
plt.ylabel('Capacitance pF')
plt.xlim(5, 500)
plt.ylim(-20,20)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you can change columns names:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'X_Axis':[1,3,5,7,10,20],
                   'col_2':[.4,.5,.4,.5,.5,.4],
                   'col_3':[.7,.8,.9,.4,.2,.3],
                   'col_4':[.1,.3,.5,.7,.1,.0],
                   'col_5':[.5,.3,.6,.9,.2,.4]})

dfm = df.melt('X_Axis', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')
g = sns.catplot(x="X_Axis", y="vals", hue='cols', data=dfm, kind='point')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but instead of typing my data into a dictionary, I have translated my data from excel 
data = pd.read_excel(path)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
and then converted this to a dictionary - dict1 = (data.to_dict()) with this as the output -- {'Frequency ': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 200, 4: 500}, 'C1': {0: 12, 1: 10, 2: 8, 3: 6, 4: 4}, 'C2': {0: 12, 1: 4, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: -5}, 'C3': {0: 17, 1: 10, 2: -10, 3: 4, 4: 1}, 'C4': {0: -7, 1: -2, 2: 10, 3: -5, 4: -2}} – Since these dictionaries are nested, how can i extract information from this?

Comment: If you want to show data on a plot, you should use a dataframe. Share your code and base with me in full and I'll get back to you.